Absolute sum of Fourier Coefficients on a finite field.
Let $ f : \mathbb{F}_q \mapsto \mathbb{C} $ be a function on a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ and let
$f(x)=\sum_{a \in \mathbb{F}_q} \hat{f}(a) \cdot \chi_a(x)$ be its Fourier sum with respect to additive characters.
Are there optimal (general) bounds for the sum $\sum_{a\in \mathbb{F}^{*}_q} \left| \hat{f}(a) \right|$?
Actually, I am particularly interested in the case where $f$ is the indicator function $\mathbb{1}_S$, of some subset $S\subset \mathbb{F}_q$. I could trivially bound the sum in this case by $|S|$, but I was wondering if there is something better.
What about the analogous sum for the multiplicative Fourier Coefficients if we consider $S\subset \mathbb{F}^{*}_q$ and $f=\mathbb{1}_S$ as a function on $\mathbb{F}^{*}_q$?
We could also use Cauchy-Schwarz and then Plancherel's equality, but I was also wondering if there is a better bound for these special functions.
